# Trying to Combine Values and Count in Multiple Fields in Same Table

Tags: sql, ms-access, coldfusion

I have a membership list database table (.MDB MS-Access, accessed via ColdFusion ) with four email address fields (email1, email 2, email3, email4) - ALL IN SAME TABLE.

I need to develop a query to produce a list of all the Email Service Provider domains (e.g. gmail.com, comcast.net, etc.) along with a count of how many of each there are, combined across ALL FOUR of these fields. The desired result SHOULD be a single list that looks like:

```
comcast.net (6)
gmail.com (14)
cs.com (1)
hotmail.com (4)
att.net (12)
aol.com (2)
 . . . . etc.
```

So far, I am able to do this for each field individually, but when I created the following Query of Queries to UNION across all four fields, I get close to what I want, but it is listing the totals for each individual field instead of adding them up. So, I get:

```
att.net (2)
att.net (3)
att.net (9)
att.net (13)
aol.com (6)
aol.com (4)
aol.com (1)
aol.com (8)
. . . etc.
```

instead of the desired:

```
att.net (27)
aol.com (19)
. . . etc.
```

How can I get them to combine all together? Thanks for your help! Here is my code:

```
<!--- get list of ESP domain names (e.g. comcast.net) from members' email addresses --->
<!--- email address one --->
<cfquery name="cfqGetESP1" datasource="#member_datasource#">
SELECT MID(email1, INSTR(email1, '@') + 1)
AS esp
FROM tblMembers
WHERE email1 IS NOT NULL
</cfquery>
<!--- email address two --->
<cfquery name="cfqGetESP2" datasource="#member_datasource#">
SELECT MID(email2, INSTR(email2, '@') + 1)
AS esp
FROM tblMembers
WHERE email2 IS NOT NULL
</cfquery>
<!--- email address three --->
<cfquery name="cfqGetESP3" datasource="#member_datasource#">
SELECT MID(email3, INSTR(email3, '@') + 1)
AS esp
FROM tblMembers
WHERE email3 IS NOT NULL
</cfquery>
<!--- email address four --->
<cfquery name="cfqGetESP4" datasource="#member_datasource#">
SELECT MID(email4, INSTR(email4, '@') + 1)
AS esp
FROM tblMembers
WHERE email4 IS NOT NULL
</cfquery>

<!--- Query of Queries to get COMBINED total instances of EACH ESP --->
<!--- across ALL four email address fields --->
<cfquery name="cfqCountESP" dbtype="query">
    SELECT esp, COUNT(esp) AS instances
FROM cfqGetESP1
GROUP BY esp    
    UNION
SELECT esp, COUNT(esp) AS instances
FROM cfqGetESP2
GROUP BY esp
    UNION
SELECT esp, COUNT(esp) AS instances
FROM cfqGetESP3
GROUP BY esp    
    UNION
SELECT esp, COUNT(esp) AS instances
FROM cfqGetESP4
GROUP BY esp
ORDER BY esp ASC
</cfquery>

<!--- test display --->
<p>TEST DISPLAY COUNT ESP ACROSS ALL EMAIL ADDRESS FIELDS<br>
<cfoutput>
<cfloop query="cfqCountESP">
#cfqCountESP.esp# (#instances#)<br>
</cfloop>
</cfoutput>
```

Comment: This is a real pain in MS Access.  Can you use any other databases?

Comment: Might also consider normalizing the email addresses. This query would be a lot simpler if the addresses were stored in rows, rather than columns: `MemberEmail (Columns: MemberID, EmailAddress)`. That structure is also more flexible, allowing as many or as few emails per member as needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to replace this query:

```
SELECT esp, COUNT(esp) AS instances
FROM cfqGetESP1
GROUP BY esp    
    UNION
SELECT esp, COUNT(esp) AS instances
FROM cfqGetESP2
GROUP BY esp
    UNION
SELECT esp, COUNT(esp) AS instances
FROM cfqGetESP3
GROUP BY esp    
    UNION
SELECT esp, COUNT(esp) AS instances
FROM cfqGetESP4
GROUP BY esp
ORDER BY esp ASC
```

with this:

```
SELECT esp, COUNT(*) AS Instances
FROM
(
    SELECT MID(email1, INSTR(email1, '@') + 1) AS esp
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE email1 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MID(email2, INSTR(email2, '@') + 1) AS esp
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE email2 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MID(email3, INSTR(email3, '@') + 1) AS esp
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE email3 IS NOT NULL
    UNION ALL
    SELECT MID(email4, INSTR(email4, '@') + 1) AS esp
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE email4 IS NOT NULL
) t
GROUP BY esp
ORDER BY esp
```

This will wrap the base UNION queries together into one dataset and then aggregate that.  (I went to query the base table again, you could easily do the same against the queries you built.)

By the way, you shouldn't use UNION in this situation, and instead, UNION ALL.  UNION will take only distinct rows out of the whole unioned dataset.  So if you had, say, att.net - 27 in email 1 and the SAME stats in, say, email 2, one of those rows would drop out and you would be short 27 instances in your aggregate query.  That would be incredibly frustrating to debug, as it would only pop up sometimes.  UNION ALL will preserve all rows from the inner unioned query.

Comment: I got a QoQ syntax error "(. when I tried to use QoQ, so I reverted to base table as you have it, and it works great!  I'm a novice at SQL and knew it had to be some sort of compound query.  I've sweated over this for days!  Thank you so much!

Comment: @user3784919: Just for clarification, I see what you were trying to do with your Cold Fusion queries (not a CF person here), like cfqGetESP1.  I thought those queries you were putting together were in Access.  That's why you got the errors.  Ok, I get it.  Yeah, in this case, have to go back to the base tables.  Glad it worked out for you.

Comment: @VBlades, ColdFusion query of queries is a handy piece of kit but has a lot of limitations.  For example, it does not have an instr() function, nor anything resembling such.

Comment: @VBlades - One more question for outputting results. If I run the following to get, for example, all addresses with domain 'Comcast.net', I get a syntax error from the part of the WHERE clause where I want to extract the substring 'comast.net' after the '@' in the email address.  How would I do that?  (I am using ColdFusion <CFQUERY> against MS-Access .MDB tables -- not using the MS-Access app itself.)  Thanks!

Comment: <cfquery name="test" datasource="membership">
    SELECT email_address
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE email_address IS NOT NULL
    AND MID(email_address, INSTR(email_address, '@') + 1) = 'comcast.net'
    </cfquery>

Comment: @user3784919: Your query seems ok to me.  Maybe it wants the first parameter for InStr, start character?  So INSTR(1, email_address, '@') + 1)?  If not, can you try double quoting instead of single?  Looks good to me, though.  If not, maybe open another question.

Comment: @VBlades - Simplified query to     <cfquery name="test" datasource="membership">
    SELECT email_address
    FROM tblMembers
    WHERE MID(email_address, INSTR(email_address, '@') + 1) = 'comcast.net'
    </cfquery> but get "Error Executing Database Query. [Macromedia][SequeLink JDBC Driver][ODBC Socket][Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver] Data type mismatch in criteria expression." Tried adding start character and double quotes, but got various other error messages.

Comment: @user3784919: The query is valid is MS Access.  You didn't seem to have email_address in the table in your previous queries, it looked like email1, email2, etc.  Other than that, the query should work.  I think you mark this one answered and you should open another question for this at this point.